# Testing Entune 3.0 of a dealer-owned 2018 Sienna LE

Tags: toyota, testing, sienna, buying, dealer

I'm in the process of test driving a used 2018 Sienna LE from Hertz Car Sales. Between my mechanic and I, we have tested everything I wanted tested, except the Entune 3.0 system.

When trying to connect my phone to Entune, I get this message: "Vehicle Not Linked. As a dealer-owned, fleet or commercial vehicle, we are unable to link this vehicle to your app or register you for Toyota Connected Services."

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to test the Entune system before I buy the car? Is taking it back to the dealership and having them demo it the only way?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It makes sense that the feature would be locked out on an unsold car. One would expect that when the purchase is completed, the connection can be established. I agree that a demonstration from the dealer may be a suitable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that is actually your best bet. If you can get them to "show you how it works" and it fails for them like it does for you, then you might be able to get them to change whatever it is needing to be changed so it will work. If you buy the car, then take it back to them, it's going to cost you money. Getting them to do it before hand will save you time, energy, and money.